# Rails merge duplicates if value is matching or nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, merge, duplicates

I'm trying to perform a clean up of some data.

I have details in various forms with various duplicates.

```
models/object.rb

attr_accessible :name, :email, :assoc_id
```

I want to merge duplicates where the name is matching and the email is either matching or nil, and the assoc_id is either matching or nil.

Not sure how I write the query to bring back groups of objects that are either matching or nil..

i.e.

```
grouped_objects = Object.group_by{|o| [o.name]}
```

brings me grouped just on the name

```
grouped_objects = Object.group_by{|o| [o.name, o.email]}
```

brings me grouped on name and email.

the issue is that many of the objects have missing data.

Just want a quick and dirty so that, in the absence of other information, I'll merge the records together.

However, if there's someone with a different email, or a different assoc_id I won't merge that. Appreciate that there'll be some false records, but what we'll end up with will be an improvement

How do I write that activerecord query?

```
 grouped_objects = Object.group_by{|o| [o.name, o.email || o.email == nil]}
```

Hope that makes sense,

Comment: I am not sure to understand why you want to merge these objects. Do you want your object be unique by name and email (and permits empty email) in your database ?

Comment: Most of the objects are auto-generated by another process that is run by the system. That process doesn't always have access to the full information, but is relating to the same 'people' (or objects). At present we have a big mess of multiple duplicate records which clearly relate to the same people. I'd like to clean that up a touch. I want to merge them as they are related to other objects in teh database wher eit would make sense to know they're the same person as a relation

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is too make your model intolerant with duplication. You can prevent duplication directly in the model. So when your controller try to create an object, it checks before if it doesn't exist by some element you decide.

So if you want your object be unique by some element, better do something like that (assuming you want the uniqueness from name and email field) in `MyModel.rb` :

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :assoc_id

  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :allow_nil => true # or :allow_blank => true

  # Your code...

end
```

You can also use `:case_sensitive => false` if you don't want upper case be differenciated from lower case.

Hope this is what you are looking for !

Comment: Not really, to be honest... I don't want to stop the process doing what it's doing. It's more important that we get the information in sensibly than that it is unique. 
Bascially we're collecting this data (thousands every day) so over time we generate large numbers of separate records that actually refer to the same person.